# Spring MVC REST: Method to Search Active Directory using LdapTemplate, LdapContextSource and SpringSecurityAuthenticationSource

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-ldap

I have a spring MVC REST application. I have implemented Spring security with AD as authentication provider. I need to implement some controller methods which can help in searching AD. Hence I defined a user details service that autowires `LdapTemplate` to perform the query on AD.

**UserDetailsSvc.java**

```
@Component
public class UserDetailsSvc {

    @Autowired
    LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserDetailsSvc.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public UserDetails getUserDetails(String username) {
        // Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        // logger.info("Auth Details: " + authentication.getPrincipal() + "/" + authentication.getCredentials());

        AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
        filter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectClass", "user"));
        filter.and(new EqualsFilter("userPrincipalName", username));

        logger.info("AD filter: " + filter.encode());
        LinkedList<Map<String, String>> list = (LinkedList<Map<String, String>>) 
                 ldapTemplate.search("", filter.encode(), new UserAttributesMapper());
        logger.info("AD Search complete");

        UserDetails ud = new UserDetails();
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            // Should only return one item
            ud.setName(username);
            ud.setDetails(list.get(0));
        }
        return ud;
    }

    private class UserAttributesMapper implements AttributesMapper {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> mapFromAttributes(Attributes attributes) throws javax.naming.NamingException {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            logger.info("UserAttributesMapper: " + attributes.toString() );

            String fullname = (String) attributes.get("displayName").get(); 
            String email = (String) attributes.get("mail").get(); 
            String title = (String) attributes.get("title").get();
            String image = (String) attributes.get("extensionAttribute1").get();
            String username = (String) attributes.get("uid").get();

            map.put("fullname", fullname);
            map.put("email", email);
            map.put("title", title);
            map.put("image", image);
            map.put("username", username);

            logger.info("user details : " + map.get("fullname") + map.get("email") + map.get("title") + map.get("image") + map.get("username"));

            return map;
        }
    }
}
```

Snippet of spring security xml files.

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
    <beans:property name="ignorePartialResultException" value="true" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
  <beans:property name="url" value="${ldap.url}" />
  <beans:property name="base" value="${ldap.basecn}" />
  <beans:property name="authenticationSource" ref="authenticationSource" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="authenticationSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.authentication.DefaultValuesAuthenticationSourceDecorator">
  <beans:property name="target" ref="springSecurityAuthenticationSource" />
  <beans:property name="defaultUser" value="{ldap.defuser}" />
  <beans:property name="defaultPassword" value="{ldap.password}" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="springSecurityAuthenticationSource"
  class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.SpringSecurityAuthenticationSource" />
```

The problem is `ldapTemplate.search` throws `NullPointerException`. Can you please help?

Here is the exception I got:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:542)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.SimpleDirContextAuthenticationStrategy.setupEnvironment(SimpleDirContextAuthenticationStrategy.java:44)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.setupAuthenticatedEnvironment(AbstractContextSource.java:155)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getAuthenticatedEnv(AbstractContextSource.java:481)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getContext(AbstractContextSource.java:106)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getReadOnlyContext(AbstractContextSource.java:125)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:259)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:571)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:556)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:431)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:451)
    at com.vmware.concorde.appadm.service.UserDetailsSvc.getUserDetails(UserDetailsSvc.java:44)
    at com.vmware.concorde.appadm.web.UserController.findUsers(UserController.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)

    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
```

...

---

Thanks 
Kalyan

Comment: Unrelated: before starting your custom AD authentication implementation have you tried [built-in AD support](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/ldap.html#ldap-active-directory)?

Comment: I have used built in alos. but I wanted override loadUserAuthorities. I did not make any change except to remove final to extend ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider. Do you think it is related to this problem somehow?

Comment: By the way, my AD authentication is working fine. I need to implement some REST api calls to search users, groups in AD and associate custom permissions and store them in a DB. Users who login do not have a right to modify AD and hence the permissions need to be stored in a custom DB. In addition to this I am storing information related user sessions (time in, time out etc.,) in my own DB. So, CustomUserDetails is not very helpful to me as I need to search details about other users (not the user who logged in).

Comment: The problem appears to be caused by your `SpringSecurityAuthenticationSource` bean returning a `null` password when the `getCredentials()` method is being called on it. Not sure why that is happening though.

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/ldap/130283-search-active-directory-with-ldaptemplate-ldapcontextsource-sp-sec-auth-sou-rce

dont use the DefaultValuesAuthenticationSourceDecorator, if you want to use only default user and password. The DefaultValuesAuthenticationSourceDecorator try to use the spring security user in session to perform the actions in LdapContext:

Solution:

```
<beans:bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
    <beans:property name="ignorePartialResultException" value="true" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
  <beans:property name="url" value="${ldap.url}" />
  <beans:property name="base" value="${ldap.basecn}" />
  <beans:property name="user" value="${ldap.defuser}" />
  <beans:property name="password" value="${ldap.password}" />

</beans:bean>
```